# How to attach multiple IAM roles to instance profile on AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using Terraform to create IAM and EC2 as below.

I want to attach a role named `ec2_role` to the EC2 instance profile. But it seems it only can attach one that created by `aws_iam_instance_profile`.

```
resource "aws_instance" "this" {
  # ..
  iam_instance_profile    = aws_iam_instance_profile.this.name
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "this" {
  name = "ec2-profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.ec2_role.name
}
```

About the `ec2_role`, it uses an `ec2_role_policy`. But if I set `source_json = data.aws_iam_policy.amazon_ssm_managed_instance_core.policy` to `data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_role_policy" {`, it throws an error.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role" {
  name               = "ec2-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ec2_role_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_policy" {
  name   = "ec2-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ec2_use_role_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ec2_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ec2_policy.arn
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "amazon_ssm_managed_instance_core" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_role_policy" {
  source_json = data.aws_iam_policy.amazon_ssm_managed_instance_core.policy

  statement {                                   # Doc A
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
      type        = "Service"
    }
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_use_role_policy" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:iam::12313113231:role/s3-role"]
  }
}
```

The error message is:

```
Error: Error creating IAM Role ec2-role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
    status code: 400, request id: 1111111-3333-2222-4444-2131331312

  with aws_iam_role.ec2_role,
  on main.tf line 10, in resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role":
   10: resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role" {
```

If I remove the `source_json = data.aws_iam_policy.amazon_ssm_managed_instance_core.policy` from the `ec2_role_policy`, it works. But how to set it with `Doc A` together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@hars34](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16916210/hars34) [mentioned in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69192714/2291321), an instance profile can only contain one role but that role can have multiple policies attached to it. But that's not what you're doing there or what the error is complaining about.

Instead, you seem to be confused with the [`assume_role_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#assume_role_policy) (also known as a ["trust policy"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#term_trust-policy), this controls what IAM principals are allowed to use the role such as other AWS services or different AWS accounts etc) of a role and the role's [permissions policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#term_policy) for what the role is allowed to do (eg read and write to an S3 bucket).

In the `assume_role_policy`/trust policy document you must specify a valid trust policy which must include a `Principal` block and cannot include a `Resource` block which is what your error message is complaining about:

```
Error: Error creating IAM Role ec2-role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
    status code: 400, request id: 1111111-3333-2222-4444-2131331312
```

Because you've concatenated your trust policy allowing EC2 instances to assume the role with a permission policy that looks like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
                "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
                "ssm:GetDocument",
                "ssm:DescribeDocument",
                "ssm:GetManifest",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:ListAssociations",
                "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
                "ssm:PutInventory",
                "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
                "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
                "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
                "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
                "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
                "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
                "ec2messages:FailMessage",
                "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
                "ec2messages:GetMessages",
                "ec2messages:SendReply"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

which contains `Resource` blocks.

If you want the role to be able to use the `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` policy and also be able to assume the `arn:aws:iam::12313113231:role/s3-role` role (although it would be more normal to give the permissions directly to the role rather than use role chaining and if this involves cross account access to use [the S3 bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-policies.html) to allow that role instead) then you should instead do this:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_role" {
  name               = "ec2-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ec2_assume_role_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ec2_permission_policy" {
  name   = "ec2-policy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ec2_permission_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ec2_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ec2_permission_policy.arn
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "amazon_ssm_managed_instance_core" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
      type        = "Service"
    }
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ec2_permission_policy" {
  source_json = data.aws_iam_policy.amazon_ssm_managed_instance_core.policy

  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    resources = ["arn:aws:iam::12313113231:role/s3-role"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It's very clear for me now. For the instance role, yes, it's using for cross accounts, and also want to use `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore`. Your code is the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

An instance profile can contain only one IAM role, although a role can be included in multiple instance profiles. This limit of one role per instance profile cannot be increased. You can remove the existing role and then add a different role to an instance profile. You must then wait for the change to appear across all of AWS because of eventual consistency. To force the change, you must disassociate the instance profile and then associate the instance profile, or you can stop your instance and then restart it.Please refer the below documentation for further queries,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html